# Plotting shp file in leaflet, works in ggplot

Tags: r, leaflet, shapefile

I'm stumped getting my dataframe to plot in leaflet. I have one shapefile and one csv that I merged together. The resulting dataframe has several columns, including long, lat, and "percent".

I am able to plot this using ggplot with the following code:

```
p <- ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = nyc_plotData, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, 
                                      fill=percent)) +
    geom_polygon(data = county, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), 
                                      fill=NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
    coord_map(xlim = c(-74.26, -73.71), ylim = c(40.49,40.92))
```

The result is a choropleth map of income distribution in nyc:

[image: nyc plot]

When I try to use the same dataframe in leaflet, I get this error:

> Don't know how to get path data from object of class data.frame

I understand I have to reformat my dataframe. I tried various ways to convert to a SpatialPolygonDataFrame. For example:

```
xy <- nyc_plotData[,c(1,2)]
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = nyc_plotData,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

gives the following error:

> Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = nyc_plotData, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")) : 
>     unused arguments (coords = xy, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

I'm clearly missing something, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this problem anywhere online.

I'd really appreciate any tips or advice dealing with shapefiles and plotting in leaflet.

Comment: Since I do not see your leaflet code, I am not sure what is happening. Yet, I think you can use both data.frame and spatial class objects in leaflet; you may not have to convert data.frame to SPdataframe.

Comment: `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` is defined as `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr, data, match.ID = TRUE)`. You need to convert to `SpatialPolygons` first. There's an example in `help("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class")`

Comment: @jazzurro, thanks for your reply.
With the following leaflet code: leaflet(nyc_plotData) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons()
I get the following error:
Error in polygonData.default(data) : 
  Don't know how to get path data from object of class data.frame

Comment: @hrbrmstr Shouldn't leaflet be able to make use of the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` without any further support?

Comment: @Konrad OP was trying to convert a fortified data frame to a SPDF directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others point out (and you note) you'll need to convert to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. In order to do this I think you'd need to convert each tract to a `Polygon`, then `Polygons`, then `SpatialPolygons` and finally a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. There is code below for this.

An alternative: You started with a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and then used `fortify` to map with `ggplot2`. You could go back to the original `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and merge the data slot with your tabular census data (being careful not to change the row order).

I put more detail on both options [here](http://bit.ly/1OEB4HT).

```
library(dplyr)
library(sp)

polyFunc<-function(groupname, dat){
  poly<-filter(dat, id==groupname) %>% 
    select(long, lat)
  return(Polygons(list(Polygon(poly)), groupname))
}


tracts <- distinct(ggtract, id, percent)
tractname <- tracts$id
polygons<-lapply(tractname, function(x) polyFunc(x, dat=ggtract)) 
sp.polygon<-SpatialPolygons(polygons)
df.polygon<-SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp.polygon, 
                                     data=data.frame(row.names=tractname, tracts))
```